# Не запускается nginx в контейнере docker

Tags: nginx, docker

Настраиваю LEMP Stack в разных контейнерах Docker. При старте все контейнеры поднимаются, а nginx нет (Status Exit -1). В чем может быть проблема? Запускаю на инстансе AWS EC2.

Comment: Нужен вывод лога.

Comment: а локально запускается?